# Не всегда подсвечивает отслеживаемые метки

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, метки, избранные-метки

Или я что-то не понимаю? Отслеживаю [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А это случайно не список вопросов по метке был?

Comment: @Qwertiy именно, а что?

Comment: да уже задубликатили - там вроде расписано?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В списках по метке, не подсвечиваются вопросы по самой метке.
Второй вопрос подсветился, так как Вы дополнительно отслеживаете [vue.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) (*Я прав?*)

Comment: Очень похоже на правду